# Uncaught ReferenceError: createUserWithEmailAndPassword is not defined at HTMLFormElement

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication

html

```
    <!-- modal de registro -->
  <div class="modal fade" id="RegistroModal" tabindex="-1">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <h5 class="modal-title">registro</h5>
          <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
            <form action="" id="registro-form">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="text" id="registro-user" class="form-control" placeholder="email" required>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="password" id="registro-pass" class="form-control" placeholder="password" required>
                </div>
                <hr>

                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Registrar</button>


            </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- Firebase -->
  <script type="module">
    import { initializeApp } from "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.14.0/firebase-app.js";
    import { getAuth, createUserWithEmailAndPassword, signInWithEmailAndPassword }  from "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.14.0/firebase-auth.js";
    
    const firebaseConfig = {
      apiKey: "",
      authDomain: "",
      projectId: "",
      storageBucket: "",
      messagingSenderId: "",
      appId: ""
    };
  
    // Initialize Firebase
    const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
    const auth = getAuth(app);
  </script>
  <script src="js/main.js"></script>
```

main.js

```
const login_form = document.getElementById('registro-form');

login_form.addEventListener('submit',(event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    const email = document.getElementById('registro-user').value;
    const password = document.getElementById('registro-pass').value;

    createUserWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, password)
    .then((userCredential) => {
        // Signed in 
        const user = userCredential.user;
        console.log(user);
        // ...
    })
    .catch((error) => {
        const errorCode = error.code;
        const errorMessage = error.message;
        console.log(errorCode);
        console.log(errorMessage)
        // ..
    });
});
```

[image: Error Google console]

When putting the data of firebase "firebaseConfig" how can I do so that when entering username and password and executing submit it does not throw the image error
"Uncaught ReferenceError: createUserWithEmailAndPassword is not defined     at HTMLFormElement."

Answer (score 0):

Modules don't create global variables. They have their own scope.

The script `main.js` doesn't have access to the variables defined by the module.

1. Move the module to its own file.
2. `export` the values you want that module to share.
3. Make `main.js` a module
4. Inside `main.js`, `import` the values from step `2` from the module module at step 1

Comment: thanks, that makes a lot of sense